# Changing some specific xticklabel styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

I would like to change some `xticklabel` styles but not all of them only few and not in specific positions (so it wont be 1st or last always).
How could I change only lets say (3,5) labels to (Hello, World) and change their font size, make them bold and underline them?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\title{Hello}
\author{}
\date{} % remove to get todays date
\begin{document}
\maketitle % prints the info from \title, \author, \date
\begin{adjustbox}{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{enlarge y limits={value=0.15,upper}}
\pgfplotsset{xtick style={draw=none}}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
       group size=1 by 2,
       vertical sep=1.8cm
       },
       /pgfplots/ymin=0,
       height=10cm,width=20cm,
    ybar stacked,
    /pgf/bar width=1.66667cm,           
    legend style={at={(0.5,1.125)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1,font=\Large},
    ylabel={\%},
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    xtick=data,
    x=2cm,                         
    enlarge x limits={abs=1.16667cm},  
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east, inner sep=5pt},
        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
    ]

\nextgroupplot
\addplot+[fill=green,ybar,draw=black] plot coordinates {(1,5.07379)(2,5.94374)(3,6.18943)(4,7.70475)(5,20.8031)(6,2.14308)(7,8.02659)(8,1.30789)(9,31.2347)};
\addplot+[fill=brown,ybar,draw=black] plot coordinates {(1,2.66531)(2,0.87115)(3,1.52316)(4,0.350975)(5,0.299016)(6,0.216008)(7,4.20682)(8,0.237877)(9,1.20268)};
\legend{\strut action 1, \strut action 2}

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT after Zarko's comment**
[image]

So i tried to implement this red box around this `very long text` but it overprint itself on `3` and red square is only around that `3`. How Could I fix it?

Comment: By use of  `extra x ticks={...}` for which you define separate label style by `extra x tick style={ ..., tick label style ={...}, ...}`.

Comment: Thank you man. I saw cool option that there is `extra x tick style={tick label style={draw=red}}` which draws red square around coord but if my `extra x ticks={3},` and I change `xticklabels={1,2,kind of long text,4,5,6,7,8,9},` my new text is printed on top of that number 3 and red square is around only `3`. How can I fix it

Comment: @Zarko I edited my question. Can you tell what im doing wrong?

Comment: Where you use `extra ticks` you should not use `ticks` (there should be empty space). Sorry, but  I'm currently busy with other  obligation and can't prepare an answer now.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks to you bro I figured it out. Thanks you very much man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Zarko I figured it out :)
[image]

1. Remove `xticklabels` you want to make special
2. Add index to labels you want to make special
3. Set those special labels
4. Set those special label styles

Thanks Zarko!

Comment: I'm glad that you solve your problem yourself. +1!. You can accept own answer :-).